# suffix changing identifier before readed?

Tags: c++

I Cant really undersdand suffix. I know it first uses identifier and then increases or decreses , as first shows `i` and then `++`. But now i think im wrong and still don't understand it.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    cout << i << i++ << i;
    cout << "\n\n\nPress Enter to close the window . . . ";
    cin.clear();
    cin.sync();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
101


Press Enter to close the window . . .
```

first `i` is changed before increment readed.Why?

I expected

```
001

Press Enter to close the window . . .
```

Can someone explain.

Comment: Did you actually read any of the answers in the marked duplicate before accepting the answer? Because the answer you accepted is clearly incorrect.

Answer (score 5):

Just never do such a thing, it is undefined

```
 cout << i << i++ << i;
```

better do

```
 cout << i << i << (i + 1);
 i ++;
```

if you want your expected result.

---

The case

```
  cout << i++;
```

is defined and perfectly ok.

Comment: unfortunately, this does not explain why and what is *undefined*.

Answer (score -1):

I think what is undefined*) here is the *order* of evaluation of function arguments. What you are actually calling here are function calls to the (overloaded)

```
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream&, int);
```

and the first argument is the output of another call to the same function, so your

```
cout << i << i++ << i;
```

expands to

```
operator<<( operator<<( operator<<(cout,i), i++), i);
```

As the order in which function arguments are evaluated is not specified, anything can happen here. You can avoid that by writing separate lines:

```
cout << i;
cout << i++;
cout << i;
```

which expands into the harmless

```
operator<<(cout,i);
operator<<(cout,i++);
operator<<(cout,i);
```

*) edit: to be more precise, the `cout<<i<<i++;` is *undefined* because the order of evaluation of function arguments in *unspecified*.

Comment: -1 Order of evaluation of arguments to a function is not Undefined, it is Unspecified. Unspecified & Undefined are not the same.Also, your description does not explain correctly why this is Undefined Behavior. Check the answers in the marked duplicate to know exactly this is Undefined Behavior.

Comment: @Als why do you criticise me instead of edit and correct? I thought this site is for mutual help not a race for being more clever than others. btw, I obviously didn't follow the duplication link.

Comment: Are you expecting me to edit and correct your incorrect answer when i already answered this in very much detail [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10782963/452307) Since you don't understand you should ask and resolve your doubts not post incorrect answers.Downvoting is a means to indicate incorrectness or displeasure towards an answer.I downvoted your answer because it is incorrect.Lastly, If you can't take criticism don't post. FYI your answer is still Incorrect.

Comment: @Als why do you think I cannot take criticism?