# Operator << - order of parameter evaluation

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior

From this question & the answers - [What is the correct answer for cout << c++ << c;?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782863/what-is-the-correct-answer-for-cout-c-c)

I get that

```
std::cout<<c++<<c;
```

is evaluated as:

```
std::operator<<(std::operator<<(std::cout, c++), c);
```

so the undefined behavior comes from the fact that either of the two parameters could be evaluated first. So far so good.

But why `std::operator <<`? Why isn't `std::ostream::operator <<` called? And if it is, wouldn't it translate to

```
(ofstream::operator<<(c++)) << c;
              |
     returns ofstream&
```

What's the difference between this and method chaining:

```
struct A
{
    A& foo();
    void goo();
};
//...
A a;
a.foo().goo();
```

?

Comment: There isn't much difference. If you do `a.foo(c++).goo(c)` you have the same problem again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::ostream` provides `operator<<` as overloaded member operators, but other headers (e.g. `<string>`) provide free operators; so whether `<<` is a member operator or a free function depends on the RHS type.

However, it doesn't matter either way.  Let's rename `<<` as `foo` and `cout` as `bar`:

```
foo(foo(bar, c++), c);
bar.foo(c++).foo(c);
```

In both cases behaviour is undefined because there is no requirement on the implementation to evaluate the arguments to either call to `foo` in any particular order.  The important consideration is that per Annex C, a chained method call does not constitute more than one *full-expression*; if the compiler sees

```
foo.bar(<some-complex-expression>).baz(<another-complex-expression>);
```

it is free to apply CSE and reordering to the arguments to `bar` and to `baz`; indeed examination of side effects may show that the arguments to `baz` are evaluated before those to `bar`.

```
struct A { A &foo(int) { return *this; } };
#include <cstdio>
int main() { A().foo(printf("hello\n")).foo(printf("bye\n")); }
```

My compiler (gcc 4.1.2) generates a program which prints `bye\nhello\n`.

Comment: The first sentence is incorrect, it depends on the [type of argument](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt)