# increment and decrement output behaviour

Tags: c++, gcc, codeblocks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the correct answer for cout << c++ << c;?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782863/what-is-the-correct-answer-for-cout-c-c)

this is my piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
int val = 10;
cout << "\n" << val++<< " "<< ++val << " " << val;
cin.get();
return 0;
}
```

The output returns

```
11 12 12
```

But shouldn't it be

```
10 12 12
```

?

I read somewhere that in case of cascading multiple values, the calculations go from right to left but the printing takes place from left to right as usual. Is that true ?

Comment: Or this one: http://stackoverflow.com/q/949433/10077

Comment: Although the functions are called in a left-to-right sequence, the arguments are not necessarily evaluated left-to-right.  You are invoking undefined behaviour, so the compiler's output is correct regardless of what it gives.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Your question was closed rather quickly because it was the same question as one that someone else had asked.  They got a decent answer to the question, too.  Please don't hesitate to ask more questions, but do try to find out whether the question has been asked before.

Comment: I think post increment and pre-increment value result different when you assign it to another vatiable but both increment increase its value.For eg `int p=val++;' and 
`int q=++val;` increase the value of val but the assignment to p and q is before increment and after increment...

Comment: @NarayanKandel: That's true, but that fact has no bearing on the problem presented in this question.