# prefix/suffix increment

Tags: c++, c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Post Increment and Pre Increment concept?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445706/post-increment-and-pre-increment-concept)

Can any one explicitly explain how prefix increment differs from suffix increment?

also can someone explain why this output 6?

```
i=1;
cout << ++i + ++i;
```

also why this gives 4

```
i = 1;
cout << ++i + i++;
```

and why this produces true

```
i = 0;
cout << (i++ || i++)
```

Comment: case 1 I think it should be 5 not 6.

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12551576/pre-increment-and-post-increment

Comment: I think you may benefit from doing some more background reading about c/c++. The code you have specified where more than one increment is applied to the same variable is unspecified behaviour. That means that the compiler can do what it wants. This is not always what you expect.

Comment: Why write code that you need to scratch your head to figure out what is going on? Just leads to problems in the future for either yourself or another programmer. Code should be readable.

Comment: Since this question concerns sequence points and undefined behavior, I think this is a better duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/could-anyone-explain-these-undefined-behaviors-i-i-i-i-i-etc

Comment: @Will with the exception of the last, `cout << (i++ || i++)` is kosher, there's a sequence point after the evaluation of the first operand of `(||)` [the lingo changed, nowadays, the evaluation of the first operand of `(||)` is sequenced before the evaluation of the second].

Answer (score 3):

The prefix `++i` and suffix `i++` operators affect the order in which the statement is evaluated. With the prefix `++i`, the value of `i` is incremented, and that is what is used. But with the suffix `i++`, the original value of `i` is used, and then it is incremented for anything following that line.

Comment: What do you mean by “compare”?

Comment: What he meant is that with i++ the compiler adds before incrementing and with ++i the compiler increments first and then adds

Comment: Rewrote it, to be (hopefully) more clear.

Answer (score 3):

1) Pretty obviously, "++i" increments the variable first, and "i++" increments afterward.

2) Less obviously, complex expressions mixing infix increment/decrement with other operations on the same variable can introduce *undefined behavior*:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point

I agree: the thread [Post-increment and Pre-increment concept?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445706/post-increment-and-pre-increment-concept) addresses this question.