# Operators precedence in PHP

Tags: php, operator-precedence

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [prefix/suffix increment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12862733/prefix-suffix-increment)

Official php manual on [operator precedence](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) has the following strange piece of code and comments to it:

```
// mixing ++ and + produces undefined behavior
$a = 1;
echo ++$a + $a++; // may print 4 or 5
```

Can someone explain me why it says that it may print 4 or 5 in some cases?
For me it's obvious, that it will firstly increment $a (to value of 2), then will summarize $a and $a (4) and only after that it will change the $a value to 3. So, result should be 4.

Comment: Please do not write code like this - it is unclear and unreadable. If you go down this avenue you are going to have all sorts of problems in the future with writing code.

Comment: @Ed Heal To be fair to him, that's not his code. It's copied and pasted from the PHP manual.

Comment: @Kenzo - That is why I use the comment feature.

Comment: This isn't about operator precedence, but about operand precedence. The suffix expression have a higher binding, but the plus operation doesn't define which operand (and thus subexpression) is evaluated first. It's just that, undefined.

Comment: I'm not going to write such a crappy code, but I want to understand why PHP behaviour in that case is unpredictible

Comment: @mario, I don't agree with your explanation. If the increments are synchronized between the calls the evaluation order does not matter.

Answer (score 1):

Update. This does *not* give a full answer. I can't show clearly how you'd get 5.

What I write below is based on what is true for C++, it may help Precedence does not control the order in which the parts of a statement is executed, and the effect of one statement does not automatically (at least it's not guaranteed) update the variable across the statement.

For example:

```
a=1 
b=a++ ; // b is 1, a is 2 
c=++a ; // c is 3, a is 3
```

Now think about writing c+b. That will evaluate to 1+3=4. But when you write

```
a++ + ++a
```

there's no guarantee from the language that a will be updated after each of the individual incrementation.

So you may as well get the effect of

```
a=1 
b=a++ ; // b is 1, a is 2 
a=1 ; 
c=++a ; // c is 2, a is 2
```

Resulting in 3

This actually has little to do with precedence or even the evaluation order. 
For example, if the variables were guaranteed to be updated within a statement, flipping the order of evaluation you'd get 4 no matter what.

```
a=1 
c=++a ; // c is 2, a is 2
b=a++ ; // b is 2, a is 3
```

Comment: From your explanation I understood that update of $a in (++$a) does not mean that in ($a++) $a can still have value equal to 1. Am I right?

Comment: But in that case the answer would be 3 or 4, not 4 or 5

Comment: @WildOne, yes. I agree. 5 is unexplained so far.