# ++ operator precedence in PHP

Tags: php, operators, addition

```
$i = 1;
$sum = $i + ($i++);
```

OR

```
$i = 1;
$sum = $i + $i + ($i++);
```

Will get result `$sum = 3` in the end, who can tell me why?

This is the test code in php.You can excute it yourself or directly click this link:[Demo](http://demo.zjmainstay.cn/php/simpleAdd.php) to check excution result.Why this result get in the end?

I want to menthion here that I know clearly what does the $i++ and ++$i do.And this question I ask is a little different.Please take a look at the "Result list".

```
$sum = $i + ($i++);  //$sum = 3;
```

and

```
$sum = $i + $i + ($i++); //$sum = 3;
```

got the same result!!

I know the code should be written in this way.I've got this from a friend and can not explain the reason,so just ask for a clearly explain here.

```
// Result list
// $i = 1;                              //Result
// $sum = $i + ($i++);                  //3 2   (Look at this)
// $sum = $i + $i + ($i++);             //3 2   (And this)
// $sum = $i + $i + $i + ($i++);        //4 2
// $sum = $i + $i + $i + $i + ($i++);   //5 2

// Test

$i = 1;
$sum = $i + ($i++);
echo   "Result: ", $sum, " ", $i, "<br />";

$i = 1;
$sum = $i + $i + ($i++);
echo   "Result: ", $sum, " ", $i, "<br />";

highlight_file(__FILE__);
```

Comment: Thanks for the random piece of code. It'd be great if you can explain what's this code supposed to do and what ***exactly*** you need help with.

Comment: Doesn't.  Even.  Matter.  If you're writing code like this, it's already broken.

Comment: I just want to kown the reason why this result.The excute principle behind the result.

Comment: The code disppear part of mine here you can see.I'm trying to display it out. You can look up here:http://demo.zjmainstay.cn/php/simpleAdd.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [Operators precedence in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13075365/operators-precedence-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right in 5.4 I got following:

```
$sum = $i + ($i++);      //3 2  , but should be 2 2
$sum = 0 + $i + ($i++);  //2 2  , correct 
$sum = $i + $i + ($i++); //3 2  , correct
```

I have tested under 5.0.5 and have another result.

"Operator precedence and associativity specify grouping, but they do not specify in which order the groups are executed. In the last example either `($a + $a)` or `($a++)` could run first.

PHP does not specify what will actually happen. One version of PHP can give you one result and a different version another. Don't write code that depends on some particular evaluation order."
https://gist.github.com/nikic/6699370

Comment: If this is a bug,I think I've got the answer.Thanks.

Comment: @Zjmainstay After some research and I have tried post a bug, I got response. I have updated my answer for this.

Answer (score 5):

$i++ means add 1 after handling the $i variable.

++ is an operator, you have to place it in FRONT of the variable you want to manipulate, this way it will add 1 BEFORE handling the variable.

```
$i = 0;
echo $i++; will echo 0;
$i = 0;
echo ++$i; will echo 1;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Technically, ++ is an `operation`, not a function; and test your code, it doesn't give what you say

Comment: And I was about to correct the last one, good thing you knew what I ment ;)

Comment: Thanks for answer. I know what $i++ and ++$i do.But it is something different here.$i=1; $sum = $i + ($i++); and $i=1;$sum = $i + $i + ($i++); is a little different,but get the same result $sum=3.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the fundamental topics in C-like languages, including PHP, and is called operator precedence.

`i++` is executed *after* the assignment, while `++i` is executed before.

Example:

```
$i = 1;
$j = 1 + $i++; // this is the same as : j = 1 + i; i += 1;
// Result: i = 2, j = 2;
```

and

```
$i = 1;
$j = 1 + ++$i; // this is the same as : i += 1; j = 1 + i;
// Result: i = 2, j = 3;
```

[Proof](http://ideone.com/Zvsid7).

Comment: Thanks,but why not compare the different between "$i+($i++)" and "$i+$i+($i++)" ;