# c++ strange std::cout behaviour using pointers

Tags: c++, iostream, cout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the correct answer for cout << c++ << c;?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782863/what-is-the-correct-answer-for-cout-c-c)

I just ouputted text, when I suddenly noticed.

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{    
 int array[] = {1,2,3,4};                 
 int *p = array;

    std::cout << *p << "___" << *(p++) << "\n";
    // output is  1__1. Strange, but I used  brackets! it should be at
    // first incremented, not clear.
    p = array;


   std::cout << *p << "___" << *(++p) << "\n";
   // output is 2_2   fine, why first number was affected? I didn't intend 
   // to increment it, but it was incremented
   p=array;


   std::cout << *p << "___" << *(p + 1) << "\n";
   // output is 1_2 - as it was expected
   p = array;

 return 0;
}
```

Such behaviour is strange for me, why is it so?

Comment: The usage of the increment with arguments in the same expression is invoking undefined behavior.

Comment: See [Undefined behavior and Sequence points](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are causing [undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior), so anything can happen and there's no point in speculating about why.

The expression

```
std::cout<<*p<<"___"<<*(p++)<<"\n"
```

Is one example: the order of evaluation of all the things between `<<` is unspecified, so `*p` and `*(p++)` are unsequenced with respect to each other (i.e. the compiler is not required do do either one first). [You are not allowed to modify a variable and then use it without the modification and usage being sequenced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points), and so this causes undefined behaviour.

The same thing applies to all the other places in that program where a variable is modified and used unsequenced separately in the same expression.