# Order of execution in operator <<

Tags: c++, stream, operator-keyword, cout, ostream

I have difficulties in understanding the sequence of calls in the code below.
I was expecting to see the output below

```
    A1B2
```

While I can see that the output I get is

```
    BA12
```

I thought that the call `std::cout<< b->fooA() << b->fooB() << std::endl` was equivalent to call

```
  std::cout.operator<<( b->fooA() ).operator<< ( b->fooB() )
```

but I can see that this is not the case. Can you help me understanding better how this does it work and the relationship with the global `operator<<`? Is this last ever called in this sequence?

```
#include <iostream>

struct cbase{
    int fooA(){
        std::cout<<"A";
        return 1;
    }
    int fooB(){
        std::cout <<"B";
        return 2;
    }
};

void printcbase(cbase* b ){
    std::cout << b->fooA() << b->fooB() << std::endl;
}

int main(){
    cbase b;
    printcbase( &b );
}
```

Comment: You are correct in thinking that it is equivalent to that. However, you are making the mistaken assumption that there is a well-defined order of evaluation. There isn't. That is all.

Comment: Order of subexpression evaluation is not guaranteed here (and it *has* to be a duplicate, but I can't find a good canonical question right now)

Comment: `AB12` or `BA12` are possible outputs. `A1B2` is not (hopefully).

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate but the answers to this question do explain the unspecified order you are experiencing. [What is the correct answer for cout << c++ << c;?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782863/what-is-the-correct-answer-for-cout-c-c)

Comment: @jrok yes, it is. (assume < means "is before") Every combination where: A < 1 && B < 2 && 1 < 2 is valid.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The compiler can evaluate the function `printcbase()` as this:

```
void printcbase(cbase* b ){
    int a = b->FooA();    // line 1
    int b = b->FooB();    // line 2
    std::cout << a;       // line 3
    std::cout << b;       // line 4
    stc::cout << std::endl;
}
```

or some of many permutatins of lines marked as 1 - 4. You are only guaranteed that that the line 1 is done before the line 3, and line 2 before the line 4 (and of course line 3 before line 4). Standard does not say more and indeed you can expect different results with different C++ compilers.

Comment: one constraint is missing line 3 is before line 4.

Comment: Well, right that is so obvious, it was not a point of my thinking. I'll add it. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

The order of execution of `<<` is well defined but the order of evaluation of sub-expressions is not defined in C++. [This article and the C code example](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/EXP10-C.+Do+not+depend+on+the+order+of+evaluation+of+subexpressions+or+the+order+in+which+side+effects+take+place) illustrates the problem you mentioned.

`BA12` and `AB12` are both correct. In the following code:

```
std::cout<< b->fooA() << b->fooB()
```

`1` will appear before `2` but `A` could appear before or after `B` since the **compiler does not promise** whether it will evaluate `fooA` or `fooB` first.

Answer (score 5):

The shift operators are left-associative; `a << b << c` is read as `(a << b) << c`, meaning that if `a` is of a type with member user-defined `operator<<` (and returns that type) then the expression reads as `a.operator<<(b).operator<<(c)`.  If instead a free `operator<<` is used, then this reads as `operator<<(operator<<(a, b), c)`.

So the evaluation of `a << b` is sequenced before the evaluation of `(a << b) << c`, but there is no sequencing dependency between the evaluation of `b` and `c`:

```
a << b << c[1]
|         |
a << b[2] |
|    |    c[5]
a[3] b[4]
```

If we number the side-effects as above, then the side-effects can be sequenced as any of:

```
54321
53421
45321
43521
43251
35421
34521
34251
```

Answer (score 1):

Since C++17, from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order

> 19. In a shift operator expression `E1 << E2` and `E1 >> E2`, every value computation and side effect of E1 is sequenced before every value computation and side effect of E2

You are guaranteed that:

```
std::cout << b->fooA() << b->fooB() << std::endl;
// (((std::cout << b->fooA()) << b->fooB()) << std::endl);
```

is evaluate from left to right, resulting in output `A1B2`.

For previous version, guaranties on output are only:

- `A` before `1`
- `B` before `2`
- `1` before `2`

so one of `A1B2`, `AB12`, `BA12`.