# Unexpected output on using pass by reference in C++

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference

Consider the code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int refcube(double &ra)
{
ra*=ra*ra;
return ra;
}

int main()
{
auto x=2.0;
cout<<"cube of "<<x<<" is "<<refcube(x)<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
cube of 8 is 8
```

Why the value of `x` at the first is displaying as `8` instead of `2`?

Comment: Some answers here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14809978/order-of-execution-in-operator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because evaluation order is not specified.

The compiler may generate the code to call `refcube(x)` and compute its value before or after generating the code to obtain the value of `x`, for output to `std::cout`.

Your compiler chose to compile this C++ code as calling `refcube(x)` first, and then by evaluating `x`.

The C++ language specification spends quite a few pages on the topic of "sequencing", which (very loosely speaking) specifies the evaluation order. To make a long story short, in this example, `x` is not sequenced with respect to `refcube(x)`, in the expression that generates the output to `std::cout`, and such a compiler is free to compile either portion of the expression first.

Comment: How to specify the evaluation order then? Any simple example for the same code?

Comment: Break it up into two separate statements: `cout<<"cube of "<<x; cout <<" is "<<refcube(x)<<endl;`