# What is logic behind output of this code postfix and prefix on same varible in one line c++

Tags: c++, operator-precedence, prefix

How for post increment(a++) return 5. As according to operator precedence a++ should execute first and should return 4.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a=4,b=4;
    cout<<++b<<" "<<b++<<" "<<a++<<" "<<++a<<endl;
    return 0;
}
Output: 6 4 5 6
```

Comment: Which version of C++ are you compiling for?

Comment: IIRC the evaluation order of stuff into a stream is not guaranteed. i.e. `a++` can be evaluated AFTER `++a`. The only guarantee is the results being shown in certain order. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14809978/order-of-execution-in-operator

Comment: You should take a look at [Order of evaluation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order)

Comment: @chris C++ 11. I got order is undefined. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always compile your code with warnings enabled. The compiler will tell you that the outcome might be undefined:

```
prog.cc: In function 'int main()':
prog.cc:6:22: warning: operation on 'b' may be undefined [-Wsequence-point]
     cout<<++b<<" "<<b++<<" "<<a++<<" "<<++a<<endl;
                     ~^~
prog.cc:6:41: warning: operation on 'a' may be undefined [-Wsequence-point]
     cout<<++b<<" "<<b++<<" "<<a++<<" "<<++a<<endl;
                                         ^~~
```

If you want to use and modify one variable with in the same expression, you need to check the [order of evaluation and sequence rules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order) to see if it is valid, and what the expected result is.

Comment: Thanks @t.niese  for telling warning enable and link. I got my answer.