# Order of writing to a global variable from

Tags: c++, constructor, global-variables

In the program below I call a function `foo()` which sets a global variable `i`
and then calls the constructor of `class A`, where `i` should also be set, but
to `10`. However the output of my program is `3  0`, can you please explain?

```
#include <iostream>

int i;

class A
{
    public:
        ~A()
        {
            i=10;
        }
};

int foo()
{
    i = 3;
    A ob;
    return i;
}

int main()
{

    std::cout << "i = " << foo() << " " << i << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Hint: add a second `cout` line, printing the value of `i`. It should print `10`.

Comment: Also note that you are setting `i` to `10` in `A`'s *destructor*, not its *constructor*, like you claim.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two important points to consider here:

The order of evaluation of arguments to a function is **Unspecified**. So either:

- `foo()` gets executed first or
- `i` gets printed first

It is specific to your compiler. Looks like your compiler evaluates argument from right to left, hence the global `i` which is `0` gets evaluated as `0`. Remember that this order may be different for other compilers and you should not rely on behavior of one implementation.

As for why `3`? The destructor for `ob` gets called after the function returns. So `i` gets set to `10` after the return, what gets returned is a copy and that copy has a value `3`.

Comment: The second point (about the destructor) I understood. Can you brief about the order of evaluation of arguments?

Comment: @NishithJainMR: Perhaps [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10782963/452307) old answer of mine will help you understand.

Answer (score 1):

Its because return value gets copied after destructor.
I gets printed first and foo gets called later so the output 3 0.

If you print like below

```
cout << "i = " << i <<" " << foo()<< endl;
```

you will see 10 3 as output.

Comment: You still need to explain the `0` :-)

Comment: That is technically wrong: the order of evaluation is unspecified. SO which ever order you see is an implementation detail. You can't rely on it.

Comment: Ok. Its undefined. the compiler which I'm verifying is showing the above result.

Comment: Undefined behavior or Unspecified behavior or Implementation defined behavior are very specific technical terms.You should understand them and use them in right contexts.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you are passing the 'i' as the argument, it's value is zero. The foo() will change the value in the destructor to 10 AFTER that.

As juanchopanza suggested, add another line std::cout << i; and you will see what you expect, because at that point the value is 10.

Answer (score 0):

Print the `foo()` and `i` by using two cout statements as follows,

```
    cout << "i of foo = " << foo();
    cout <<"\ni in main = " << i << endl;
```

The output will be

```
    i of foo = 3
    i in main = 10
```

Earlier you were getting `3 0` as output because the overloaded operator `<<` was being evaluated from left to right by your compiler.