# C++ Array passed by reference, but how to understand this?

Tags: c++, arrays, reference

The arrays are passed by reference. Any changes made to the array within the function `changeArray` will be observed in the calling scope (`main` function here).

However the codes below print `0 1` in the 1st `cout`, and print `2` in the 2nd "cout". What I don't understand is that why the first `cout` prints the original value of `array[0]=1` instead of the changed value of `array[0]=2`?

Thanks a lot.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int changeArray(int array[]) {
    array[0]=2*array[0];
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    int array[]={1,2,3,4};
    cout << changeArray(array) << " " << array[0] << endl;
    cout << array[0] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782863/what-is-the-correct-answer-for-cout-c-c and many other order-of-evaluation questions

Comment: Arrays are not passed by reference; in fact, arrays cannot be passed as arguments at all. `int changeArray(int array[])` really means `int changeArray(int *array)` (it's adjusted at compile time), and the array expression `array` in `changeArray(array)` is implicitly converted to ("decays" to) a pointer the array's first element for reasons unrelated to the fact that it's used as an argument in a function call.

Comment: @KeithThompson "arrays cannot be passed as arguments at all" Arrays can be passed by reference in C++: `int changeArray(int (&array)[4])` However, arrays of *unknown bound* cannot be passed by reference.

Comment: @DyP: Good point. (I'd go back and edit my comment if I could.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make sure that the compiler doesn't reorder the execution:

```
cout << array[0] << endl;
changeArray(array);
cout << array[0] << endl;
```

This prints 1 and then 2.

The C++ compiler is allowed to optimize the code by reordering the execution of code within a single expression (e.g. `cout << changeArray(array) << " " << array[0] << endl`). To avoid that, and to make sure `changeArray` gets called first, you need to split your expression to separate statements, e.g. by using the semicolon (`;`). Everything before the semicolon gets executed before anything after the semicolon can start.