# Multiple statements in a single cout produce different results

Tags: c++

```
int x;
int fun1()
{
    x=x+10;
    return x;
}
int main()
{
    x=5;
    cout<<x;
    cout<<fun1();
}
```

this produces 5 and 15 while

```
cout<<x<<fun1();
```

this produces 15 and 15. Please explain. Thankyou

Comment: See this answer for the sequence of evaluation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782863/what-is-the-correct-answer-for-cout-c-c

Comment: Insert newlines in your output for clarity. Right now the output will be e.g. 515 without \n.

Comment: Maybe it will be clearer if you write out the actual [`operator <<`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2) invokes as they're defined. Try writing them as nested function calls. The selected answer for the question linked by Gerriet goes into detail in doing so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In c++ reference, order of evaluation of arguments of `std::cout` is unspecified. It is not left-to-right, right-to-left, or anything else.

Please avoid this. Instead use separate calls.

[see also](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point)

Comment: cout << a << b << c has a well-defined order. The problem is the function call, not the ordering per se.

Comment: @Brandin, what about ``std::cout << c++ << c ;`` [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782863/what-is-the-correct-answer-for-cout-c-c) . Not function just call, but evaluations in general.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, thanks. corrected the ambiguous sentence.