# Understanding index++ in single line of code

Tags: c++, c

This is a part of the code snippet for a merge sort implementation and I have trouble understanding this line:

```
b[bIdx++] = (a[left] <= a[right]) ? a[left++] : a[right++];
```

I am re-writing the above snippet to check my understanding of the line. Is my understanding of the above line correct?

```
if (a[left] <= a[right]){
    b[bIdx] = a[left];
    left++;
}
else { 
    b[bIdx] = a[right];
    right++;
}
bIdx ++;
```

Comment: Yes. Your code is correct. The postfix `++` is evaluated after the operand’s value is used but before the next statement is evaluated. Recent versions of C++ tightened the spec to reduce UB but AFAIK/IIRC it’s still UB in some cases but in your case it’s fine.

Comment: By "next statement", do you mean the next line of the code? Or in the one liner, is `b[Bidx++]` one statement, and ``a[left++]`` another statement

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the correct answer for cout << a++ << a;?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782863/what-is-the-correct-answer-for-cout-a-a)

Comment: Does your conversion have the same behaviour?

Comment: Yes its correct, you understood right.

Comment: you should learn to do quick unit tests on small snippets of code in order to verify yourself

Answer (score 2):

Your understanding is correct.

The postfix increment operator `++` evaluates to the *current* value of its operand, and as a side effect increments its operand.  The effect of the increment is guaranteed to be visible at the next **sequence point**.

A sequence point occurs after each statement, but it could occur within an expression based on the operator.  Examples of operators that create a sequence point are the logical AND operator `&&`, the logical OR operator `||`, the comma operator `,`, and as in your case the ternary operator `?:`.

Breaking down the single line statement, the condition `a[left] <= a[right]` is evaluated first.  There is now a sequence point in this stage of the evaluation.  Based on the result of this condition, either `a[left++]` or `a[right++]` is evaluated, and whichever is evaluated is assigned to `b[bIdx++]`.  There is a sequence point here at the end of the statement, at which point `bIdx` is incremented and either `left` or `right` is incremented.

The above is reflected in the multiple statement version of the code.  The condition is evaluated first, then `b[bIdx]` is assigned either `a[left]` or `a[right]`, then either `left` or `right` are incremented, then `bIdx` is incremented.

Answer (score 0):

Your re-written code is equivalent to the single line of code above.

The single line uses the postfix increment operator in which the value of the expression is evaluated i.e. `a[left]` is evaluated with the current value of `left` after which the operand `left` is incremented by 1.

Also note that there also exists a prefix increment operator in which the operand is incremented by 1 after which the value of the expression is evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

Is my understanding of the above line correct?
Correct.
even more we'll clear doubts, ensure it by

```
if (a[left] <= a[right]){
    b[bIdx] = a[left];
    ++left;
}
else { 



    b[bIdx] = a[right];
    ++right;
}
++bIdx;
```

space in else e.g. above is for code filled in if you have more condition e.g. such

```
b[bIdx++] = (a[left] < a[right]) ?  a[left++] : ( a[left++] == a[right] ? (++right, 1)  : a[right++] );
```

Comment: you are also correct ++right or right++ which are used independently like
right++;
++right; 
do the same thing